# Can you read JSON into Laravel and turn into DOM element?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a JSON file with text. I want to print that out into a div and have an anchor tag inside it.

I have the JSON -

```
    {
        "text" : "A bunch of text here with a <a href="#">link</a>"
    }
```

Inside my controller, I decode the JSON

```
    $json = Storage::disk('local')->get('settings.json');
    $json = json_decode($json, true);
    return $json;
```

Inside my view

```
    <p>{{ $text }}</p>
```

At the moment the p tag would just echo the response as a string

> A bunch of text here with a <a href="#">link</a>

How can turn this into html? Is that even a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically Laravel does html entity encoding when you print something using `{{ $text }}`.

In order to not to encode HTML elements, you have to use

```
{!! $text !!}
```

This can be also used for web page rendering as well for many other use case.

Comment: That was awesome. Thanks